# Atualizar sweetalert 1.x para sweetalert 2 + javascript promises

Tags: javascript, jquery, promises, sweetalert

Ao atualizar a biblioteca [SweetAlert](https://sweetalert.js.org/) ela parou de funcionar, ao debugar o erro vi que teve muitas modificações que tornaram a versão 1.x incompativel com a nova versão, então eu gostaria de ajuda para transcrever minha função `deletarRegistro()`.

Código da função com sweetalert 1.x

```
function deletarRegistro() {
    if (id_row > 0) {
        swal({
                title: "Você tem certeza disso?",
                text: "Uma vez deletado, não há como desfazer!",
                type: "warning",
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
                confirmButtonText: "Sim, delete isto!",
                showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
                closeOnConfirm: false
            },
            function () {
                $.post('/api/tdocumentos/delete', {id: id_row})
                    .done(function () {
                        tbl_api.row('.info').remove().draw(false);
                        swal("Deletado!", "Seu registro foi deletado.", "success");
                        id_row = null;
                        formulario.reset();
                        $(tab_lista).click();
                    })
                    .fail(function (response) {
                        console.log(response.responseText);
                        swal("Erro!", response.responseText, "error");
                    })
                ;
            })
        ;
    } else {
        tbl_dependentes.effect('shake');
        return false;
    }
}
```

A documentação do SweetAlert 2.0 da esse exemplo:

```
swal({
  title: "Are you sure?",
  text: "Once deleted, you will not be able to recover this imaginary 
file!",
  icon: "warning",
  buttons: true,
  dangerMode: true,
})
.then((willDelete) => {
  if (willDelete) {
    swal("Poof! Your imaginary file has been deleted!", {
      icon: "success",
    });
  } else {
    swal("Your imaginary file is safe!");
  }
});
```

Pergunta: Gostaria de saber como posso transcrever a função usando promisses, e saber o que o uso de promisses melhora na função.

Answer (score 0):

Após mais algumas horas de video aulas, consegui solucionar essa parada, segue o código atualizado pra ver como ficou, infelizmente não sei explicar os detalhes :(

```
function deleteData() {
    if ( id_row > 0 ) {
        swal({
            title: "Você tem certeza disso?",
            text: "Uma vez deletado, não há como desfazer!",
            icon: "warning",
            dangerMode: true,
            buttons: {
                cancel: {
                    text: "Cancelar",
                    visible: true,
                    value: false,
                    closeModal: true,
                },
                confirm: true
            },
            closeModal: false,
            closeOnClickOutside: false,
        })
            .then((resolve) => {
                if (resolve) {
                    $.post('/api/sinodos/delete', {id: id_row})
                        .done(function () {
                            tbl_api.row('.active').remove().draw(false);
                            swal("Deletado!", "Seu registro foi deletado.", "success");
                            id_row = null;
                            cadastros_sinodos.reset();
                        })
                        .fail(function (response) {
                            console.log(response.responseText);
                            swal("Erro!", response.responseText, "error");
                        })
                    ;
                } else {
                    swal.close();
                }
            })
        ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Por qual o motivo que você atualizou? Observando o código não vi melhorias aparentes. Talvez algo relacionado ao código interno do próprio sweetAlert2?

Comment: @guastallaigor Sim, a estrutura do código teve de ser alterada pois o componente Sweetalert mudou de versão e com isso algumas coisas foram descontinuadas, por isso tive que implementar desta forma que respondi.